# SDL_ttf текст не выводится в opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl2

Вот SDL_ttf функция:

```
void RenderText(std::string message, SDL_Color color, int x, int y, int size) {
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluOrtho2D(0, gWindowWidth, 0, gWindowHeight); // m_Width and m_Height is the resolution of window
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    TTF_Font * font = TTF_OpenFont("pathToFont.ttf", size);
    SDL_Surface * sFont = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, message.c_str(), color);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, sFont->w, sFont->h, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sFont->pixels);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
    glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2f(x, y);
    glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2f(x + sFont->w, y);
    glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2f(x + sFont->w, y + sFont->h);
    glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2f(x, y + sFont->h);
    }
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();

    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);
    TTF_CloseFont(font);
    SDL_FreeSurface(sFont);
}
```

Вызываю в функции

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    outStream.setCodec(QTextCodec::codecForName("cp866"));

    if(!initOpenGL())
    {
        outStream << QString("GLFW инициализация провалилась") << flush;
        std::cerr << "GLFW обявление провалилось "<< std::endl;
        return -1;
    }


    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)==-1)
    {
        printf("SDL_Init: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    if(TTF_Init()==-1){
        printf("TTF_Init: %s \n", TTF_GetError);
        return -1;
    }


    // Rendering loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(gWindow))
    {
        // Poll for and process events
        glfwPollEvents();
        // Clear the screen
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // рисуем второй треугольник
        //      My_TwoSquares();
        // Рисуем цикл
        //      My_Circle();
        // Рисуем порабулу
        //      My_Parabola();
        // Рисуем спираль
        //      My_flat_sprial();
        // рисую круги
        //           My_circular_circle(0.0, 0.3, 0.5);
        //           My_circular_circle(0.0, 0.5, 0.3);

        //           My_circular_circle(-0.3, -0.5, 0.3);
        //           My_circular_circle(-0.3, -0.3, 0.5);

        //           My_circular_circle(0.3, -0.5, 0.3);
        //           My_circular_circle(0.3, -0.3, 0.5);

        // рисую кoлёса
        My_circular_koleso(0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1);
        My_circular_koleso(-0.3, -0.4, 0.4, 0.1);
        // My_circular_koleso(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2);

        // Prints out "Hello World" at location (5,10) at font size 12!
        SDL_Color color = {255, 0, 0, 0};
        RenderText("Hello World", color, 25, 27, 12);


        // Swap front and back buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(gWindow);
    }

    //Clean Up

    glfwTerminate();

    SDL_Quit();

    return a.exec();
}
```

получаю такой результат :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я блокирую весь вызов SDL то всё работает.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    outStream.setCodec(QTextCodec::codecForName("cp866"));

    if(!initOpenGL())
    {
        outStream << QString("GLFW инициализация провалилась") << flush;
        std::cerr << "GLFW обявление провалилось "<< std::endl;
        return -1;
    }


//    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)==-1)
//    {
//        printf("SDL_Init: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
//        return 1;
//    }

//    if(TTF_Init()==-1){
//        printf("TTF_Init: %s \n", TTF_GetError);
//        return -1;
//    }


    // Rendering loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(gWindow))
    {
        // Poll for and process events
        glfwPollEvents();
        // Clear the screen
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // рисуем второй треугольник
        //      My_TwoSquares();
        // Рисуем цикл
        //      My_Circle();
        // Рисуем порабулу
        //      My_Parabola();
        // Рисуем спираль
        //      My_flat_sprial();
        // рисую круги
        //           My_circular_circle(0.0, 0.3, 0.5);
        //           My_circular_circle(0.0, 0.5, 0.3);

        //           My_circular_circle(-0.3, -0.5, 0.3);
        //           My_circular_circle(-0.3, -0.3, 0.5);

        //           My_circular_circle(0.3, -0.5, 0.3);
        //           My_circular_circle(0.3, -0.3, 0.5);

        // рисую кoлёса
        My_circular_koleso(0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1);
        My_circular_koleso(-0.3, -0.4, 0.4, 0.1);
        // My_circular_koleso(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2);

        // Prints out "Hello World" at location (5,10) at font size 12!
//            SDL_Color color = {255, 0, 0, 0};
//            RenderText("Hello World", color, 25, 27, 12);


        // Swap front and back buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(gWindow);
    }

    //Clean Up

    glfwTerminate();

//    SDL_Quit();

    return a.exec();
}
```

вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если вызов сделать после цикла `while`? Или же в самом цикле?

Comment: @B1aZe мнебы хотелось увидеть на экране отрисованные "колёса" и текст. плюс цикл "прикручен" как раз к закрытию окна

Comment: http://www.programmersranch.com/2014/03/sdl2-displaying-text-with-sdlttf.html?m=1 . Может поможет

Comment: @B1aZe проблема в том что я хочу в свои проекты встроить текст. А не  из за текста переходить на другой массив технологий. Вот в чём оказия . Хотя увы но я  всё более стал думать об использовании [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php) для своих планов (порно-игоры) ибо чистый опенгл очень очень  сложен и гсчялюченссс

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй запустить exe-шник не с IDE, а из папки. У меня тоже такое было(только без opengl).